# hypothesis function space in decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I am reading the book "Artificial Intelligence" by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig (Chapter 18).  The following paragraph is from the decision trees context.

> For a wide variety of problems, the decision tree format yields a
>   nice, concise result. But some functions cannot be represented
>   concisely. For example, the majority function, which returns true if
>   and only if more than half of the inputs are true, requires an
>   exponentially large decision tree.
>
> In other words, decision trees are good for some kinds of functions
>   and bad for others. Is there any kind of representation that is
>   efficient for all kinds of functions? Unfortunately, the answer is no.
>
> We can show this in a general way. Consider the set of all Boolean
>   functions on "n" attributes. How many different functions are in this
>   set? This is just the number of different truth tables that we can
>   write down, because the function is defined by its truth table.
>
> A truth table over "n" attributes has 2^n rows, one for each
>   combination of values of the attributes.
>
> We can consider the “answer” column of the table as a 2^n-bit number
>   that defines the function.  That means there are (2^(2^n)) different
>   functions (and there will be more than that number of trees, since
>   more than one tree can compute the same function). This is a scary
>   number. For example, with just the ten Boolean attributes of our
>   restaurant problem there are 2^1024 or about 10^308 different
>   functions to choose from.

1. What does author mean by `"answer" column of the table as a 2^n-bit number that defines the function`?
2. How did author derive (2^(2^n)) different functions?

Please elaborate on above question, preferably with simple example, such as n = 3.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a general truth table for a 3-input function, where the result for each triple is also a Boolean (1 or 0), represented by variables `i` through 'p':

```
A  B  C   f(a,b,c)
0  0  0     i
0  0  1     j
0  1  0     k
0  1  1     l
1  0  0     m
1  0  1     n
1  1  0     o
1  1  1     p
```

We can now represent any function on three variables as an 8-bit number, `ijklmnop`.  For instance, `and` is `00000001`; `or` is `01111111`; `one_hot` (exactly one input `True`) is `01101000`.

For 3 variables, you have 2^3 bits in the "answer", the complete function definition.  Since there are 8 bits in the "answer", there are 2^8 possible functions we can define.

Does that outline the field of comprehension for you?

**More detail on an example function**

You simply (once you see the pattern) make the eight bits correspond to the entires in the table.  For instance, the table for one-hot looks like this:

```
A  B  C   f(a,b,c)
0  0  0     0
0  0  1     1
0  1  0     1
0  1  1     0
1  0  0     1
1  0  1     0
1  1  0     0
1  1  1     0
```

Reading down the "answer" column, labeled `f(a,b,c)`, you get the 8-bit sequence `01101000`.  That 8-bit number is sufficient to completely define the function: the rows listing all the combinations of a, b, c are in a fixed (numerical) sequence.

You can write any such function in a template format:

```
def and(a, b, c):
    and_def = '00000001'
    index = 4*a + 2*b + 1*c
    return and_def[index]
```

Now, if we generalize this to any 3-input binary function:

```
def_bin_func(a, b, c, func_def)
    return func_def[4*a + 2*b + 1*c]
```

If you wish, you can further generalize the template for a list of inputs: concatenate the bits and use that integer as the index into the `func_def` string.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I didn't get your example  For instance, and is 00000001; or is 01111111; one_hot (exactly one input True) is 01101000. Can you please explain. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Got the concept now.

Comment: Great to hear it!  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.